# Types of communication between azure virtual machines (IaaS)

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to find ways of communication between two virtual machines (IaaS).

I tried WCF communication, but is there any other way to do this? I read about Azure Connect and VPN but it is more for communication between on-premise and cloud services?

What are all possible ways?

(I am new in cloud computing and Azure and detailed explanation will be very useful. Thanks.)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are looking for

- [VNET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/06/19/overview-of-windows-azure-virtual-network.aspx) communication is possible if you are looking for something like that.
- Azure IaaS instances have a public IP addresses which you can use to communicate over the Internet.